# symfony and entity manager

Tags: php, symfony

I want to do the following

I have a database table of students, and I want to output each student name in a check box list.

so

checkbox. Student 1

checkbox. Student 2

Where the value of the checkbox is the student's ID.

How can I do that using Symfony?

I want teachers to be able to select one or more checkboxes.

I tried following this tutorial:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

and using collections, but I am lost...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [Entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).